# Removing wireframe without gaps in matplotlib plot_trisurf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a smooth cylinder using matplotlib/pyplot. I've adapted a tutorial online and produced the following minimal example:

```
from numpy import meshgrid,linspace,pi,sin,cos,shape
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

u,v = meshgrid(linspace(0,10,10),linspace(0,2*pi,20))
u = u.flatten()
v = v.flatten()

x = u
z = sin(v)
y = cos(v)

tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1],projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=tri.triangles,linewidth=0)

pyplot.show()
```

which produces a [cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC0to.png). I set linewidth=0 to remove the wireframe, however, there is now the "ghost" of the wireframe because the triangulation has (presumably) been spaced assuming the wireframe is there to fill in the gaps. This looks to be specific to plot_trisurf, because there are other 3d plotting examples (e.g., [using plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html)) which set linewidth=0 without these gaps showing up.

Doing an mtri.Triangulation?, it seems like it might not be possible to "perfectly" fill in the gaps, since it states

```
>Notes
> -----
> For a Triangulation to be valid it must not have duplicate points,
> triangles formed from colinear points, or overlapping triangles.
```

One partial solution is to just color the wireframe the same shade of blue, but after I've fixed this problem I also want to add a light source/shading on the surface, which would put me back at square one. 
Is there a way to make this work? Or can someone suggest a different approach? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=tri.triangles,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that. Apparently not. Thank you.